# Sort Map<ArrayList<Key>,ArrayList<Value> by value instead of Key

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to sort the Map<K, V> but my map has both key and value as ArrayList, ArrayList. Is there an easy way to sort this type of map BY Value? Also, Value can have duplicates
thanks for your help

Comment: will this help this gives u example when value is array stackoverflow.com/questions/25123940/… if your key is array too you can do same for that –

Comment: show us your code, please

Comment: [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) does not implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). So the lists do not know how to sort among other lists. How would you decide which list comes before/after other lists?

Answer (score 0):

See the following article for how to sort a `Map` by value: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/sort/java-sort-map-by-values/

If this is not exactly what you are looking for, please provide some example code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).